# declare template friend function of template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, friend

I have a class template `Obj` and a function template `make_obj`.  `Obj` has a `private` single constructor defined, which takes a reference to its templated type to bind to.

```
template <typename T>
class Obj {
  private:
    T& t;
    Obj(T& t)
        : t{t}
    { }
};

template <typename T>
Obj<T> make_obj(T& t) { 
    return {t};
}
```

What I want is to declare the `make_obj` function a `friend` so that it can create `Obj`'s, but no one else can (except via the copy ctor).

---

I have tried several friend declaration including

```
friend Obj make_obj(T&);
```

and

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
friend Obj<T1> make_obj(T2&);
```

The latter being a less than desirable attempt at making all template instantiations of `make_obj` friends of the `Obj` class.  However in both of these cases I get the same error:

```
error: calling a private constructor of class 'Obj<char const[6]>'
    return {t};
           ^

note: in instantiation of function template specialization
      'make_obj<const char *>' requested here
    auto s = make_obj("hello");
             ^
```

trying to do `make_obj("hello");` for example purposes.

How can I allow only `make_obj` access to `Obj`'s value contructor?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need a few forward declarations:

```
template <typename T>
class Obj;

template <typename T>
Obj<T> make_obj(T t);

template <typename T>
class Obj {
private:
    T & t;
    Obj (T & t) : t(t) { }
    Obj() = delete;

    friend Obj make_obj<T>(T t);
};

template <typename T>
Obj<T> make_obj(T t) { 
    return Obj<T>(t);
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43cc98e5609e4f70)

And BTW: I don't think you really want `T & t;` for your class' member variable. Probably `T t;` is a better choice ;)

Comment: You went all the 9 yards and then dropped the ball... the friend should not be a template, but a template *specialization* :) [Only `make_obj<A>` needs access to `Obj<A>`, no need to enable access to `make_obj<Z>`!] --for the record: `friend Obj<T> make_obj<T>(T t);` instead of befriending the template

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas You are right. I fixed the answer but not the live example to leave the "old" way as a reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

With the automatic return type syntax, you only need to forward declare the function and everything works.  Here is an example

```
template <typename T>
auto make_obj(T t);

template <typename T>
class Obj {
private:
    T & t;
    Obj (T & t) : t(t) { }
    Obj() = delete;

    friend auto make_obj<T>(T t);
};

template <typename T>
auto make_obj(T t) {
    return Obj<T>{t};
}

int main() {
    make_obj(1);
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/3k86gx

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't say that substituting `T` return type with `auto` would help, but it does!

Comment: If the return type of a friend function relies on the class' scope type aliases, this is the only way.