# c++ How to apply template to child/friends of a template class?

Tags: c++, class, oop, templates, inheritance

In c++, how is it possible for child class, or friend function to access all possible template types of the parent? How do I modify the code below, so that no matter what the type `T` is, the friend function and child function will not suffer from type errors? (Currently only the type of int works properly).

```
// PARENT CLASS:¨

template <class T>
class parent{
public:
    T variable1;

    friend int function1(parent, int a);
};


//CHILD CLASS:

class child : public parent<int> {
public:
    void setvariable(int a){ variable1 = a; };

};


// FRIEND FUNCTION:

int function1(parent<int> k, int a) {
    return k.variable1 +a;
};
```

So that the following would then compile without errors:

```
int main() {
    child child1;              //Child
    child child2;

    child1.setvariable(4);
    child2.setvariable(4.4);   //Type error/retyping

    cout << function1(child1.variable1, 4) << endl;     // Function
    cout << function1(child2.variable1, 4.0) << endl;   // Type error

    system("pause");
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [declare template friend function of template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792565/declare-template-friend-function-of-template-class)

Comment: Can you show an example of code you want to have? E.g., a definition of function1? It is, to me, unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: @Jonas The definition of the function is on the 2nd to last line ;).

Comment: Well, obviously it is. But that, presumably, compiles. Do you have an example that you want to have working , but doesn't yet?

Comment: @Jonas I have added a simplistic example.

Comment: Still the question is unclear. Obviously a float cannot be converted to int...

Comment: Or do you want "friend int function1(parent, T a);" in class parent?

Comment: @AndreasH. What I want is for the child and function to work for ANY type, not just int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will allow the friend function to access variable1 for all derived types.

```
//Parent
template <class T>
class parent{
public:
    template<typename U>
    friend U function1(parent<U>& parent, U a);

private:
    T variable1;
};


//Child
class child : public parent<int> {
public:
    void setvariable(int a){ variable1 = a; };
};


//Friend
template<typename U>
U function1(parent<U>& k, U a) {
    return k.variable1 + a;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

friend function definition can be inside class definition:

```
template <class T>
class parent{
public:
    T variable1;

    friend T function1(parent k, T a) {
        return k.variable1 + a;
    }
};
```

That function is not template so allows promotion/conversion.

Comment: Very interesting, I though there was fundamentally no difference between writing the function implementation inside the class declaration vs outside.

Comment: it is the only way to define it for each template without that thefuntion is itself template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you try to achieve, but I think this could be what you want.

The `child` class and `function1` are now templates and the first parameter of `function1` is a reference.

Template parameter is explicitly set when instantiating a `child` object.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class parent{
public:
    T variable1;

template <class U>
    friend U function1(parent<U>&, U a); // now a template, using U to avoid shadowing 
};

//CHILD CLASS:
template <class T> // now a template
class child : public parent<T> {
public:
    void setvariable(T a){ this->variable1 = a; }; // using 'this' pointer because the function is a template now
};

// FRIEND FUNCTION:
template <class T> // now a template
T function1(parent<T>& k, T a) { // first parameter is a reference, for polymorphism to work
    return k.variable1 +a;
};

int main() {
    child<int> child1;    // T = int
    child<double> child2; // T = double 

    child1.setvariable(4);
    child2.setvariable(4.4); 

    cout << function1(child1, 4) << endl;   // first parameter is child1, and not the member variable
    cout << function1(child2, 4.0) << endl; // first parameter is child2
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a solution for one particular interpretation of the question. :)