# How to properly define friend free functions

Tags: c++, templates, friend-function, c++17

### Background

I'm trying to write a container which will contain iterators. E.g. it creates indirection range. I want the iterator of the range to dereference underlying iterator. I did that, but then I need relational operators. Here is the reduced version that reproduces the problem:

### mcve

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    class bar
    {
        friend bool do_something(bar);
    };

    bar get_bar()
    {
        return bar{};
    }
};

template <typename T>
bool do_something(typename foo<T>::bar)
{
    return true;
}

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    foo<int> f;
    auto b = f.get_bar();
    std::cout << do_something(b);
}
```

> /tmp/prog-c08a3a.o: In function `main':
>   prog.cc:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to`do_something(foo::bar)'

[demo on wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WorRnCrAzosI93vk).

This is the only error I get.

### Question

What is declared inside of the class and what is defined as free function outside of the class?

### What I tried

Compiler asks me to put a template, but that is clearly not what I want. I don't want my iterator related to one `ForwardIterator` type to be comparable to iterator of another `ForwardIterator` type. But I thought ok, lets try that, but it gave me shadowing error, which strengthened my suspicions.

### Reasons why I want to define inside

From what I've heard, defining it inside will make it only ADL callable. Some IDEs might not figure that out, so I thought that declaring them outside is better.

Comment: I'm sure it is a duplicate, but I couldn't find the original. I would be grateful to find an extensive answer about this one.

Comment: _complaining about_ Coyp&paste!

Comment: [Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @manni66, I'm not sure what you mean. The code is what I wrote literally 10 minutes ago. I tried to do one, but it didn't reproduce the problem. Let me see if I'll be able to reproduce.

Comment: The **error message**!

Comment: @manni66, done. I'm pretty sure it won't add much.

Comment: You have declared a non-template friend function, unrelated to the template you provide later.

Comment: @manni66,  I managed to reproduce it. Turns out I needed to think simpler.

Comment: RE: *"Some IDEs might not figure that out, so I thought that declaring them outside is better."* I may be in a minority view here, but this seems like a bad reason to do this.

Comment: @StoryTeller, relational operators are not shown in popup window, but when they parse the code they might highlight it with red, showing a problem (e.g. a == b with red underneath). It is annoying, and I would like to deal with it.

Comment: Suit yourself, but you may end up creating more problems for yourself and your IDE. Since to do what you want, the friend has to be a template too.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792565/declare-template-friend-function-of-template-class

Comment: @Holt, I anticipated that, but then the boilerplate will get to around ~60 lines. As three way comparison is not here, I would like to avoid writing more lines of boilerplate. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: gcc compiles this code with warnings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simpler would be to define the function directly in the class:

```
template <typename T>
struct foo
{
    class bar
    {
        friend bool do_something(bar) { /* implementation */}
    };

    bar get_bar()
    {
        return bar{};
    }
};
```

Comment: I guess users should file a bug report against their IDEs then. Fixing it on the code side seems to bring quite a lot of a hassle.

Comment: You don't have real good alternatives, in `template <typename T>
bool do_something(typename foo<T>::bar)`, `T` is non deducible.

Comment: @Jarod42 On top of that, the `do_something` in this answer *is not a template function*, but a non-template friend of a non-template class contained in a template struct.