# How do i get a function pointer to a friend function defined inside a template class

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers, linker-errors, friend

I want to define a template class `Foo<T>` and a template function `func<T>`, so that `func<T>` is a friend of `Foo<T>`, but `func<T1>` is NOT a friend of `Foo<T2>` for `T1 != T2`. As far as I know, there are two ways to do this.

1:

```cpp
template < typename T >
class Foo;

template < typename T >
void func(Foo<T> x);

template < typename T >
class Foo {
    friend void func<>(Foo<T>);
};

template < typename T >
void func(Foo<T> x) {}
```

2:

```cpp
template < typename T >
class Foo;

template < typename T >
void func(Foo<T> x);

template < typename T >
class Foo {
    friend void func(Foo) {}
};
```

In both cases I can call `func` like this

```cpp
int main(void) {
    Foo<int> a;
    func(a);
```

But when I try to get a function pointer

```cpp
    (&func)(a);
}
```

the second version fails with a linker error:

```
/tmp/ccOICrUD.o: In function `main':
foo2.cpp:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `void func<int>(Foo<int>)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why is that? And how do I get a function pointer to a function as in #2 above?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792565/declare-template-friend-function-of-template-class) would be a dup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template < typename T >
void func(Foo<T> x);
```

This declares, but does define, a template function.

```
template < typename T >
class Foo {
    friend void func(Foo) {}
};
```

This does ***not*** define the template and make it a friend. This effectively defines a non-template function

```
void func(foo<T>)
{
}
```

as a friend.

This is not the same thing as a template function. If you want to reference the template function, then you would do this:

```
template < typename T >
class Foo {
    friend void func<>(Foo);
};
```

Just like as in your first example. Now, neither

```
func(a);
```

nor

```
(&func)(a);
```

links, because, of course, you have not defined the template function, in your second case. And once it's defined, you effectively have the same program as your first example.

Comment: I still don't quite get the difference. How is
```cpp
void func(foo<T>)
{
}
```
not a template? It depends on T, doesn't it?

Comment: You can have an ordinary function that takes a `foo<T>` parameter, just like an ordinary function that takes an `int` as a parameter. Which is different than an instance of a template function.